# Reading a DAT file with odd characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to read and print the contents of a dat file in C. I'm still learning how to read binary files and I thought the correct way to read the file was byte by byte like so (below is just a code snippet):

```
unsigned char buffer;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("products.dat", "rb");

while (!feof(fp)) {
    fread(&buffer, 1, 1, fp);
    printf("%c", buffer);
}
```

Here is the output I receive:

```
    16010719-5109ABSORB leathercare setq�8�q�Њq�e����(\�@16011030-0456ANNO INEZ panel curtain�8�q�Њq�eH
ףp=
@16020623-8644ALVE deskpanel curtain�8�q�Њq�eq�Q��k!@16021117-5765ALVE add-on-unit for secretaryЊq�e\�(\���@16071127-9620ANTONIUS height adjustable clothes dryerЊq�e�
ףp=
@16080205-0344BEDDINGE seriesadjustable clothes dryerЊq�e�)\���(@16090505-4102ANDY drawer unit on casterslothes dryerЊq�e[\���(\@16100207-7038BEATA collectionon casterslothes dryerЊq�e��z�G��?16140311-3192BILLY systemionon casterslothes dryerЊq�e�\���(\!@16140312-0502ALVE laptop tablen casterslothes dryerЊq�e�H�z�G@16150309-1686AKURUM wall top cabinet framethes dryerЊq�e1�p=
ף@16150613-8211BEHANDLA seriescabinet framethes dryerЊq�e1)\���("@16150701-5897ANTONIUS shelfcabinet framethes dryerЊq�e��Q��@16150807-2103ANEBODA seriescabinet framethes dryerЊq�e���Q�� @16171215-4812ANTONIUS drying racket framethes dryerЊq�e�=
ףp=@16190603-3731ABSORB leathercleanert framethes dryerЊq�e���(\��#@16200211-9747BEATA ORKIDE duvet cover and pillowcase(s)Њq�e�������@16220729-5714ADMETE RUND chair pader and pillowcase(s)Њq�e_
ףp=
�?16240510-6077ANTIFONI floor/reading lamp pillowcase(s)Њq�es{�G�z@16270718-1760ALG mirroroor/reading lamp pillowcase(s)Њq�e�fffff� @@
```

I'm supposed to be able to obtain product information from this file: product code, name, quantity, and price. Is my code for reading this file incorrect?

Here's the products.dat file contents
[image: 1]]

Comment: What is the format of the file?  You'll most likely want a structure that matches that format and then you read the data into it.

Comment: `feop` or `feof`? Whatever ==> `while (fread(&buffer, 1, 1, fp) == 1)`. Moreover, you are trying to print binary data as text.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm trying to figure out the format of the file with ghex but I'm still lost.

Comment: @WeatherVane Typing error on my part, sorry about that. However, your suggestion still gives me an output with odd characters.

Comment: See the second part of my above comment. The file contains non-printing characters. Perhaps the file needs to be read *in context* with whatever wrote it.

Comment: How was the file created?

Comment: @cdarke I have no idea, I was just given the file.

Comment: Ask whoever gave it to you then!

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay, now I understand what you're saying. I can work off of that, thank you!

Comment: Those non-printable characters could represent some form of integer, but they could be of various lengths - that can even be compiler dependant.  It could come from a little-endian or a big-endian machine.  It could be a dump of a C struct where those unprintable are just pad bytes and have no meaning at all.  Without that information then all you can do is guess what those bit sequences mean.

Answer (score 0):

> You'll most likely want a structure that matches that format and then
>   you read the data into it.

You should follow that good advice from Retired Ninja. For a start:

```
    struct product { char code[15], name[51];
                     short quant;
                     double price;
                   } buffer;
    while (fread(&buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, fp))
        printf("%s\t%-51s%3d %.2f\n", buffer.code, buffer.name,
                                      buffer.quant, buffer.price);
```